# How to copy Ruby gem from one server to another

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Is there a way for a particular ruby gem (mysql gem) to be copied from one server to another (both are similar servers)?

In my case, the other server is a production server and gem install mysql is failing to compile there as rubymysqllib is missing and can't install build dependencies there.

Basically my question is: how can I copy a gem from one server to another server?

Comment: What's the point of copying the gem if it won't work since there's no proper dependencies on your server?

Comment: yes marek, you may correct but is there any other way where can compensate for build dependencies. i have already gem-compiler option, it install the gem but i get the below error when require it.LoadError: libmysqlclient.so.15: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory -/path/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/mysql-2.9.1-x86_64-linux/lib/mysql/mysql_api.so"

Comment: try to uninstall the mysql gem and again install it. it will recompile with your latest library

Comment: Gagan, reinstalling will not work on the server. as it will fail for the same build dependencies

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure out if it is a good practice but I did this way sometimes and worked.

To copy all gems I just copied and past the folder `C:\Ruby187\lib\ruby\gems\` (adapt this in accordance with your case) from one machine to another.

To copy a single gem I went inside the `gems`folder and copied the files with same name (of the gem) inside of the respective folders.

```
C:\Ruby187\lib\ruby\gems\1.8\cache
C:\Ruby187\lib\ruby\gems\1.8\doc*
C:\Ruby187\lib\ruby\gems\1.8\gems*
C:\Ruby187\lib\ruby\gems\1.8\specifications
#*doc and gems are optional
```

Another way I found, but I never did is like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9539518/best-practices-for-transfering-ruby-gems-collection-from-one-machine-to-another?rq=1).

**CAUTION**

When you copy the gems like this you are not verifying the dependencies and it may cause bad behavior of your application.